# Client freeze on reading object from socket

Tags: java, sockets

I'm developing a simple Client-Server application over socket, but I can't get why client freezes when he is reading an object.
Server must be capable of dealing with multiple client.

Keeping it simple, my Server looks like:

```
    ...
    server_thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int p = 0;
            ObjectInputStream in;
            ObjectOutputStream out;
            NetworkOffer message;    

            try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
                // get connections
                LinkedList<Socket> client_sockets = new LinkedList<>();
                while (p++ < partecipants) client_sockets.add(serverSocket.accept());

                // sending welcome object
                for (Socket socket : client_sockets) {
                    out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    message = new NetworkOffer();
                    out.writeObject(buyer_offer);
                }
            ...
```

My Client:

```
    ...
    client_thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ObjectInputStream in;
            NetworkOffer smessage;
            try {
                Socket ssocket = new Socket("localhost", port);
                in = new ObjectInputStream(ssocket.getInputStream());

                // waiting server message
  ------------->Object o = in.readObject();
                smessage = (NetworkOffer)o;


                System.out.println(smessage.toString());
                ...
```

**EDIT**: 
To make things clearer, this is the protocol I want to implement:

1. N clients connect to Server
2. Server send `welcome` to Clients
3. Every client makes an offer
4. Server chooses best offer, and sends a message to each Client with `Accept/Reject`
5. If there isn't an acceptable offer goto 3.

Client sticks on `Object o = in.readObject();` even if server has already sent his message.
No error, nothing. Thread is simply freezed there waiting for something.

What's going on?

Comment: What is 'seller_sockets', and how does it ever get populated?

Comment: Sorry, in order to simplify I have rewritten some vars, but I missed it. `seller_sockets` = `client_sockets`. I've corrected it in my question. Thank you

Comment: 1) it is always a good idea to flush() output when you finished writing, but it still will not guarantee immediate send.
How do you know that the message is written anyway? It looks to me that your server waits for **all** participants to join **before** it sends anything to any of them. Is that intended behaviour?

Comment: @Germann Arlington: yes that's what I want. All clients connect to Server; Server sends welcome; Clients send their offers; Server choose the best if any, otherwise all clients make another offer. I've just edited my question to make things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `ServerSocket.accept()` is a blocking call meaning the server will hang until somebody connects to it.  When somebody connects, the server will add that new socket to the `client_sockets`.  If the number of sockets added is less than `participants`, it will then call `accept()` again and wait for another connection.  It will only enter your `for` loop when the total number of sockets is equal to `participants`.  You need to spawn a new thread to handle each incoming client socket and allow the server to return immediately to `ServerSocket.accept()`.  Have a look at the [Reactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern) pattern for a good example of how to implement this.

What your code should look like is this:

1. Server waits for connections.
2. When client connects, spawn a new thread to handle the connection.
3. Server returns to waiting for connections.
4. New thread sends welcome message on socket, adds the socket to the list of `client_sockets` and waits for the clients offer.
5. Store the clients offer.
6. When all offers have been received, compare to find the best.
7. Send `Accept/Reject` messages.

Comment: I don't want spawn a thread for each client, because they must wait for others, so I think it's okay that `accept()` is a blocking call. What I can't understand is: all clients connects: ok. Then Server send the first "welcome"; at this point, one client thread shouldn't be freed and go on? Instead all clients are blocked on `in.readObject();`. Why this happens?

Comment: @marka.thore That's the thing, the server _isn't_ sending the welcome message until all clients have connected.  They're waiting there because the server hasn't sent anything.

Comment: No, this isn't the case. The Server thread execute correctly the while (all clients connect!) and even sends the first "welcome". After this one client thread becomes active, and freezes on `in.readObject();`

Answer (score 1):

As I said before: are you sure that the server have sent the data to the client - there is no buffer flush so it can still be cached.
`out.flush()` will make sure that buffer is flushed. 
It will make sense to handle clients separately and send them periodic messages to update them about the status.
It is useful for your server code to handle the client disconnect/connection drop too.

On the side note:

```
message = new NetworkOffer();
out.writeObject(buyer_offer);
```

Your code seems to be sending something else that is not present in your example. Is that correct?